# How can set a script to run after all photos have loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I have have spent hours trying all of the different methods given online but nothing works. I just simply want to load a script to run after all images have loaded. Is there something about Angular that won't allow me to do this? I'm using `$routeProvider`:

```
var photos = {
    name: 'photos',
    url: '/photos',
    views: {
        main: {
            templateUrl: "views/photos/photos.html",
            controller: function($scope,$http){
                $http({
                    url: 'get/photos',
                    method: "POST"
                })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                        $scope.data = data;
                        // this doesn't work
                        $(window).load(function() {
                            myScript();
                        });
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

By the way, I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: I don't know angularjs, but when I read the heading of this question I was curious about your approach. If you can get the number of photos to be loaded you could simply use a counter and then start the script when the counter is reached?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the http POST call retrieves the photos. And I am suppose that `myScript` is a function. So why not try this:

```
var photos = {
    name: 'photos',
    url: '/photos',
    views: {
        main: {
            templateUrl: "views/photos/photos.html",
            controller: function($scope,$http){
                $http({
                    url: 'get/photos',
                    method: "POST"
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                    $scope.data = data;
                    myScript();
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

since the `myScript` function only runs after the `POST` succeeds. I am supposing that the `data` refers to the actual image data.

Comment: This is what I tried originally but it didn't work. For some reason the ``myScript()`` function runs before all the photos have loaded. I realize that it should run after they are in the DOM, but the function needs to run after the images have actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood what type of data you are trying to get, but I think you could try with promises

$http in Angular already return a promise wrapped in .success or .error, but you can also use the .then() callback like with every other promise

So if the problem is to wait for the success() callback to be finished you could do something this way, replacing it by several then() :

```
$http.post(...).then(
                //function which will wait for the data to be downloaded
                //here you can alter data, check some values etc...
               ).then(
               //the script for what you want after
               myScript();
               );
```

I made a little fiddle to explain : http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2sa/2/

It simulates a long response time with $timeout, so you have to wait 3 secondes to see your modified data, which remains in its initial state until you call the myScript() function

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Angular does not provide a way to inform us when images have finished loading.
You will need to write your own directive for this.  The directive would wrap the necessary JavaScript/jQuery code that would detect the finished loading condition for one or more images.

[jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached) and https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded might help.